# Redirecting thumb.php image to prevent size and quality from showing

Tags: php, image, .htaccess

I'm trying everything to redirect users from viewing the image link when they click to open a new tab to view it because it contains size and quality in the link like this, for example, [www.example.com/thumb.php?file=/images/photo.jpg&size=120&quality=50](http://www.example.com/thumb.php?file=/images/photo.jpg&size=120&quality=50).

Since the size and quality help the pic to show the desired size and of good quality, removing it is not an option. Instead, I'm trying to get some sort of code to redirect a user to another page when trying to view the link in a new tab, or if they try changing the size or quality in URL, it does not work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried ? What webserver do you use ?

Comment: Apache web server.

Comment: You can not properly differentiate between the request the browser makes for the embedded image, and when they open it in a new tab. Plus, anyone’d be able to see the URL in your HTML code anyway. If you want to exclude the possibility that the user changes the parameters - then add a _hash_ of their values plus a secret (values plus secret concatenated into a string, then hashed), and verify that on the receiving end, before your script dynamically scales the image.

Comment: So based on the example url provided above, if a user changes the size and quality to a value  lets say 9999999 each, is there any way of implementing a PHP code to say if the values change from 120 and 50, then redirect the user to main page or something to mitigate DDOS attack?

Comment: My main concern is preventing or mitigating a user's action to change the initial values for size and quality  that they see in the URL  for specific images

Comment: You can do that by using a hash like I suggested. When the verification of that fails, then redirect elsewhere.